# Email Marketing: sending ID in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, bestpractice, id

This is a 'best practice' question:

Should we be sending a Salesforce GUID in an email? We have a button in an email to ask them for consent (to a thing). That button links to a VF Page or a Marketing cloud page (we can go either way). In either case the query string will contain the ID of the lead.

My contention is that a user could change the URL and [...klyAAE ] isn't very different to [...klYAAE] and maybe that is a record.

I get some emails from Salesforce / SFMC users and I see urls such as: http://click.e.domainname.com/?qs=07d1f922e432d9f8b76fc2ecd423c011ff2aa49fdc139daa21c87ee360df886e2b3cfc7b62180ba77a05d1afbc9d75512d7a073dfd34a5d1

So - What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice if you were to go via the Marketing Cloud Pages track would b

1. Pass on the subscriberkey or any identifier using the CloudPages Ampscript function
2. On the cloud page, use the RequestParameter function to parse the identifier

If you have integrated right, then your leadid would also be your subscriber key.

Comment: So - My question is: should we be sending the LEADID as a parameter in the clear? My contention that it isn't good practice.

Comment: You would add lead I’d using the cloud pages url function, but when you view it in browser it would be similar to the qs bit in your question

Answer (score -1):

Adam Spriggs wrote a blog post about the MicrositeURL() function, I'm pretty sure the same idea would work with the CloudPagesURL() function. This has worked great for me multiple times. Here's a link to the post:

https://sprignaturemoves.com/a-case-for-the-micrositeurl-function/

Comment: MicrosoteURL would only work with the old landing pages in email studio which is now been sun set

Comment: He wrote this ages ago ( before cloud pages url)

Comment: The OP says the the options are a VF page or Landing page, which exclude micrositeurl as an option

Comment: Yes, but the concept can be used using the new CloudPagesURL() function.